# How do I make a directory immutable in svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have certain directories in svn that should not be touched after a release.  While I can put svn:needs-lock on each file in the directory, I would like to prevent adds and deletes as well as modifications.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is through a [pre-commit hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html): verify that the commit does not contain any folders that are not to be touched, and if they do, fail

Answer (score 6):

You could prevent access to the path through permissions in the authz-file. Practically you could allow only one user to access the release-path, that the user that makes the releases. Or you disallow access after a release completely. In the authz-file you can define a path and which users has read- and write-access.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that if you remember the revision number - it's already immutable!

Here's a crazy idea - move the directory to a location under tags, and in the original location add an externals reference to the tag location pegged with the revision number.